# Better way of defining several clickable area in a single large image in Corona SDK

Tags: optimization, coronasdk

I have a large image background with several areas or objects in the images which can be clicked and an event is triggered. The method I'm currently using to accomplish this is by slicing the images of objects and area and positioning them over the background image and assigning a click handler to them.

This works for the moment but I feel that there should be a better way of doing this. One way I thought and tried is to fill the sliced images with black or white, position them over the background image, make their opacity 0, make them hit testable and assign a click handler.

Does this method have advantage over the previous one? Does making an image object transparent use less texture memory or is it the same?

And are there other better ways to do so? My main objective is about making the game use less texture memory and cutting the overall project file size by using less of those sliced images.

Answer (score 0):

Use display.newRect/newCircle to mark down area, make them transparent and hit testable.

This should be more efficient than using images.

Comment: But this can't be used for objects with irregular shapes, for example a kite on a table. This was the reason I thought of using the sliced image with its area filled with black or white to reduce it's file size, and then setting it's opacity to 0